# Should database connections be made in Reducer or from Master?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a MapReduce job in Hadoop. My reducer function for simplicity outputs the key, and count of the key's occurrence.

The next step in my pipeline is to send this data to a MySQL database(specifically an RDS instance), but I have run into issues with the reducers trying to access the jdbc driver. This is probably because the driver is not being sent to all the reducers and is only packaged in my jar.

For this program I believe instead of trying to debug the reducer, it will be easier to right another program that simply cats the data from hdfs and sends line after line to the database.

Does having each Reducer connecting to the database improve the process through the parallelization I expect? In which case, is it worth spending the time to wrestle with the Reducers jdbc driver?

Sample Output:
hdfs:///user/hadoop/out/part-r-0000

```
Key1     150
Key2     214
```

Comment: Can you give us the error message of the issues you are having?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with parallel connections to the same database. I am not sure though. 
I would suggest getting the output as one merged file, using:
`hadoop dfs -getmerge /HDFS_path /local_path`
and then bulk-loading the file into the database, instead of writing records one-by-one. Bulk-loading is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem loading a database from a reducer. You are right that such an approach can increase throughput if your database allows that and it is sometimes done this way.

If your job jar is packaged correctly (that is as Hadoop expects it) then there should be no problem. A Hadoop job jar should contain your application's classes unpacked as usual plus all the dependencies (incl. the JDBC driver) should be in the /lib folder and should be packed.

The contents of the job jar then looks like:

```
...
org/yourdomain/package/YourClass.class
org/yourdomain/package/AnotherClass.class
lib/httpcore-4.1.2.jar
lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar
...
```

There are also other approaches where you make all the dependencies available on each Hadoop node beforehand, etc.

If you are using Maven, it's quite easy to assemble such a jar using the Assembly plugin. But to quickly test it you can simply add the JDBC driver in the jar manually (in the /lib folder).